# Why is it that Smith's regeneration to Capaldi looked like he sneezed?

Tags: doctor-who

In '*Time of the Doctor*'

> the Doctor claims that he has used up all of his regenerations. So, Clara asks the Time Lords to help him, and they willingly give him an extra regeneration.

However, for the actual regeneration process itself, unlike other times when the Doctor has had his arms spread out as he regenerates, he sort of has his head jitter forward (so looks like he sneezed), then Capaldi's head appears!

It literally looks like the Doctor sneezed as he regenerated. He sneezed.

What’s going on? Why is this regeneration different from previous ones?

Comment: “I swear that Moffat hates us all, because we then have to wait another 8 months until the new series is released!” Yeah, it’s well-known that each episode of Doctor Who can be produced within 3 days, but production is never started until the last minute to enable Mr Moffat to sit behind a desk twirling his moustache, stroke a white cat, and laugh manically for several months every year.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - *[citation needed]*

Comment: -5 downvotes? I don't think this encourages new users to ask more questions. When I get even -2's on a question I ask it kind of knocks my confidence. People try not to be to aggressive. : )

Comment: @DVk - http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/8030/3c6u.png

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is a bad question by someone who hasn't even read the Tour. Straight-up. Bad and ignorant question.

Comment: Then please tell them first. Maybe they did or didn't know but it is better to warn then to putdown someone's confidence first. If they repeat flag the question, then vote down.

Comment: @Timelady Hello and welcome to the SE. I'd suggest looking at the Tour under the help menu above to better understand how to ask a good question. **Hint:** since reading the Tour gives you a badge, and you have no badges, it's obvious you have not read it.

Comment: @MiharuDante You're absolutely right. I lost my temper a little. Given her screen name and her lack of understanding and her apparent hostility toward the show-runner it seems a poor name choice. She seems like a Doctor Who fan who doesn't understand or necessarily even like Doctor Who. Apologies all around. I have no excuse or rationale for being mean. :'(

Comment: Then there’s me being a snarky, sarcastic jerk right in the first comment, that doesn’t help. I actually think there’s a good question in here — I’ll re-edit to make the tone a bit more question-y, and less discussion-y.

Comment: @MeatTrademark: I’ve edited the question to hopefully make it a good fit for the site. Maybe take a look and see if it’s worth a re-open/up-vote.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I've used this site for about 2 years now and I never knew there was a tour up until now. As a matter of fact I forgot there was even a help button, I hardly ever see it.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's a new regeneration cycle, and this is the first time we get to see a "reset" of this cycle (Matt Smith being young again before the regeneration finishes and Capaldi appears). I'm expecting Moffat/Capaldi to explain or confirm once the next series starts.

Also, I don't think Clara actually saw Amy. I think it was a hallucination by The Doctor. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: +1 for showing patience and logic. I lost my temper with this question to my shame.

Comment: “I'm expecting Moffat/Capaldi to explain or confirm once the next series starts.” I bet we get zero explanation or confirmation within the show, although Moffat might well say something in an interview.

Comment: @Tilley...Your right amy was a hallucination or him remembering her since she took up so much of his incarnations time and he was so attached to her

Comment: @giacomocasanova Actually considering he lived for over 900 years she didn't take up that much time. I think it's more that her face was the first he saw in that incarnation.

Comment: @Pharap he may have live for such a long time but spent more time with amy in one carnation than he did with any other modern companion

Comment: @giacomocasanova Actually, it's implied that he was friends with Barnable from the time barnable was a boy to the time he died. He may not be a companion but that would be a lot longer than the time he'd known Amy Pond for. In fact that's probably true for other residents of Christmas as well. On top of that he'd known River Song for a very long time. So technically you can only say he spent the most on-screen time with her than any other companion, and that still doesn't explain why he didn't see Rory, who had been there almost as long.